# Keep Record in Same Position on Screen Using Continuous (sub)Form after Update

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

The question of how to keep a record at the same position on the screen after updates has many elaborate solutions. I whittled it down to a simple solution, with a small problem.

I am using a subform. One screen displays 13 records. The position on the screen for the first record i.e. Me.CurrentSectionTop = 660 twips.  The 13th is at 7860 twips. So each record is 600 twips high.

It doesn't matter if I use Refresh or Requery.

My code looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub txtQtyOrderedA_AfterUpdate()

    RecNum = Me.CurrentRecord
    screenPosition = ((Me.CurrentSectionTop - 660) / 600) + 1
    lastRecordToShow = 13 - screenPosition + RecNum

    compID = DLookup("ID", "tblcustomers", "CompShortName = '" &  Me.txtCompanyName & "'")
    updateStr = "UPDATE tblOrderDetails " _
                & " SET ODEQtyOrdered = " & Me.txtQtyOrderedA _
                & " WHERE tblOrderDetails.ODEOrderID=" & compID & "" _
                & " and tblOrderDetails.ODEProductFK = '" & Me.txtProductID & "'"

    CurrentDb.Execute updateStr, dbFailOnError
    Forms![frmOrderDetails].Requery

    Me.SelTop = lastRecordToShow

End Sub
```

The proper record is shown as the last record on the screen thereby putting the updated record in the same position as it was before the update.

There is one problem. If I run the code in step mode (i.e. using F8) it works. If I run the code automatically (i.e. using F5) the form scrolls to the first record in the table and I have to scroll through screens to get to the updated record.

How can I stop the scrolling issue, using the code (or slight variation of the code)?

Comment: a me.refresh will not change the record position, but only show updates to existing records. A re-query will move/reset the record pointer. A simple refresh should work.

Answer (score 0):

a me.refresh will not change the record position, but only show updates to existing records. A re-query will move/reset the record pointer. A simple refresh should work.

Also why are you doing a full requery on the "main" form?

If your code is running inside the form, then  you want to use:

```
  me.SubFormControlName.Form.Refresh
```

Comment: The code is running in the subform.  That is why I chose to use me.refresh. Also, it doesn't matter if I use refresh or requery it jumps to the first record/screen.

Comment: I'm so sorry - I had changed the refresh to me.refresh in my code but I showed the old code with requery on the main form.  However, it still doesn't matter if its on the main form or the subform or if its refresh or requery.  Is there a form property that I might look at setting to help solve this problem?

Comment: A me.Requery will re-set and requery the form - the record position AND often/likely the screen position will change. With me.refresh, the selected record position will REMAIN the same. However, it certainly possible that the position on the screen may change. So no, me.refresh does not change the selected record or move the record pointer - it never does unless some additional code that "sets" or re "sets" the record source is running. So is the issue the selected record (which me.refresh) will not change, or is the "scroll" position on the screen the issue?

Comment: The issue is the scroll position. I show 13 records on a screen. If I'm on record 29, I am on the 3rd screen.  After me.refresh the screen jumps to the beginning showing record 1 in the first position not record 27.  With debug, lastRecordToShow is 39.

Comment: Use a recordset bookmark to store your current record, then restore it after your refresh / requery.

Comment: when you execute a requery (recordset or form), the book marks are invalid. The poster has "cleared" up the issue. The issue is NOT the record changes position (and it does not with me.refresh). The user wants the scroll position to remain the same. This can be done, but I'll have to dig for some code.

Comment: also, is this a sub form? you don't want to execute the me.refreash on the main form, but only on the sub form in question.

Comment: yes, this is a subform. All the code that I showed is in the subform and is triggered after an update to a text box on the subform.

Comment: There must be some other event or code running. A me.refresh will not move the record pointer, and does not change the scroll position.  I don't know if some on-current or other event is running some code, but me.refresh as a general rule does not move the scroll position, nor does it change the record pointer position. You are saying that both the record pointer and the scroll position changes as a result of me.refresh - that not what access does. Perhaps the parent form is executing some requery, but a simple me.refresh should not move anything. You above code has a me.Requery (change it).

Comment: That's part of the frustration - nothing else is going on at the time this is being run.  I even ran the subform on its own i.e. outside of the main form.  I am running Windows 10 and Access 2016.   Maybe its only the record pointer that changes but because it changes the scroll then follows - I don't know.  Your thoughts and the situation seem so simple.  I'm going to try to create a new form and new subform.  Maybe there's some sort of corruption on the form or subform.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the code for keeping the screen position the same, will try soon. 
as far as it always refreshing to top of screen when running (vs step mode), I have had luck with using Application.echo

```
Private Sub control_onclick()

    varcurrentlineid = Me.lineitemid '(current subform line item id)
    Application.Echo False

...run code that does modify data

...form!mainform.refresh (which refreshes the subform too)

   Application.Echo True
   DoEvents
   DoEvents  'seems to need  two to work

   Set rs = Forms!fmainform!fSubForm.Form.RecordsetClone
   rs.FindFirst "lineitemid=" & varlineitemid
   If Not rs.EOF Then
     Forms!fmainform!fSubForm.Form.bookmark = rs.bookmark
   End If
End Sub
```